Content overflows and scrolling create rounded corner issue
I'm trying to create cards layout. Here is my layout.
<div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "start", width: "100%", height: "auto", padding: "2rem", gap: "1rem", borderRadius: "2rem", backdropFilter: "blur(4rem)", background: "goldenrod", }}>
  <div className="text-3xl unselectable font-bold" style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row",alignItems: "center",width: "100%", height: "3rem", }}>
    <div style={{ width: "auto", height: "3rem", alignItems: "center", display: "flex" }}>
      <Meteor weight="fill" color="#f2f2f2" /> { /* Phosphor Icons */}
    </div>
    <div style={{ width: "0.5rem", height: "100%" }}></div>
    Technologies and Mastery
  </div>

  <div className="card-container-grid-2">
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>

Using this styles,
.card-container-grid-2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(100% / 3), 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 12rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

Cards are rendered nicely. But the container has overflow on Y axis, and it breaks rounded corner on bottom left and bottom right. Tried to control the scrolling overflow, but the scrollbar is unscrollable and rounded corner still sharp. How can I fix this? Any suggestions?

You need to provide more details of how you want the layout to work. Please edit your post to describe how the grid of cards should behave on different screen sizes. Are you saying that even on a phone screen you want all 8 cards to fit the screen without any overflow? What content will each of the cards contain? Please add a diagram or sketch or screenshot if that will help us understand the issue you are asking about.

Please post the generated HTML and not the template

use box-sizing: border-box; in your parent div

Please explain how this would solve the issue at hand
